# error while running shell script through jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Getting below error while trying to run shell script

```
+ /home/pqsharma/symlinkBuild.sh 19.07
sh: line 1: 21887 Terminated              sleep 3
```

With Jenkinsfile:

```
 node ('linux')
        {
    stage('creating symlink')
              {stdout = sh(script:'/home/pqsharma/symlinkBuild.sh 19.07 ',  returnStdout: true)
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is followed by [JENKINS 55308](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55308): "intermittent "terminated" messages using sh in Pipelines"

> Jenkins master runs from a Docker image based on jenkins/jenkins:2.138.2-alpine with specific plugins baked into the image by /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
>
> The message originates in durable-task-plugin, which must be a dependency of one of the `plugins.txt` plugins.

Check if this is the case for you.

Caused by [JENKINS 55867](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55867): "sh step termination is never detected if the wrapper process is killed"

> When you execute a shell step, Jenkins runs a wrapper shell process that's responsible for saving the exit code of your script. If this process is killed, then Jenkins never discovers that your script has terminated, and the step hangs forever.
>
> This seems to have been introduced after v1.22 of durable-task-plugin

Diagnostic:

> The `sleep 3` is part of the execution of a shell step.
> A background process touches a specific file on the agent every 3 seconds, and the Jenkins master checks the timestamp on that file as a proxy to know whether the script is still running or not.
> It seems based on the reports here that something is causing that process to be killed on some systems, but I don't have any ideas about what it could be offhand.

Possible cause:

> The bug is not just in the durable-task-plugin, although the symptoms come from there. It is introduced when you upgrade workflow-job. I have managed to pinpoint it down to a specific version.
>
> Upgrading workflow-job to 2.27 or later triggers the bug. (2.26 does not exist.)

So try and downgrade your workflow-job  plugin to 2.25

Comment: Not directly answer my question but TIL about how shell step works in Jenkins. Thank you :)